# How to get magento store?

Tags: php, magento

> I want to check the store type in **Magento** and run query if the store EN else another query , I have my code below but it doesn't work:

```
$name = $store->getName();
  $connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
  if($name=='EN')
  {
  $sql= "SELECT * FROM directory_country_region_EN WHERE name='$region' "; 
  } 
 else
 {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM directory_country_region_SU WHERE name='$region' "; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$name = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
$connection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
  if($name=='EN')
  {
  $sql= "SELECT * FROM directory_country_region_EN WHERE name='$region' "; 
  } 
 else
 {
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM directory_country_region_SU WHERE name='$region' "; }
```